# Regex out part of the string

Tags: regex, vb.net

I have a load of content as shown below:

```
 <td width="20%"><a href="/search?tbs=shop:1&q=camping+lantern&sampleq=1">camping&nbsp;lantern</a></td>
 <td width="20%"><a href="/search?tbs=shop:1&q=sandisk+cruzer&sampleq=1">sandisk&nbsp;cruzer</a></td>
 <td width="20%"><a href="/search?tbs=shop:1&q=leaf+blower&sampleq=1">leaf&nbsp;blower</a></td>
 <td width="20%"><a href="/search?tbs=shop:1&q=cd+rack&sampleq=1">cd&nbsp;rack</a></td>
 <td width="20%"><a href="/search?tbs=shop:1&q=trackman+mouse&sampleq=1">trackman&nbsp;mouse</a></td>
```

And i need some regex to get what is between the `&sampleq=1">` and the `</a>`

This is the regex i did my self `&sampleq=1"">(.*)<\/a>` and it is not working

Comment: Why isn't your regular expression working. Can you give an example of what it does? (Why have you written two double quotes? I guess because you are putting this inside a double quoted string...)

Comment: http://www.rubular.com/r/45lcGEEYl5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
&sampleq=1\">(.*?)<\/a>
```

Answer (score 1):

use `(.*?)` instead of `(.*)` and use s modifier if this is for php, g modifier if this is for javascript

Answer (score 0):

The smallest possible one that seems to work for me seems to be `1">.*</a`.

And here's a complete VB.Net app that tests it:

```
Module Module1
    Const a As String = "<td width=""20%""><a href=""/search?tbs=shop:1&q=camping+lantern&sampleq=1"">camping&nbsp;lantern</a></td>" & vbNewLine & _
         "<td width=""20%""><a href=""/search?tbs=shop:1&q=sandisk+cruzer&sampleq=1"">sandisk&nbsp;cruzer</a></td>" & vbNewLine & _
         "<td width=""20%""><a href=""/search?tbs=shop:1&q=leaf+blower&sampleq=1"">leaf&nbsp;blower</a></td>" & vbNewLine & _
         "<td width=""20%""><a href=""/search?tbs=shop:1&q=cd+rack&sampleq=1"">cd&nbsp;rack</a></td>" & vbNewLine & _
         "<td width=""20%""><a href=""/search?tbs=shop:1&q=trackman+mouse&sampleq=1"">trackman&nbsp;mouse</a></td>"


    Sub Main()
        Dim r As New Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("1"">.*</a")
        For Each m As Text.RegularExpressions.Match In r.Matches(a)
            Console.WriteLine(m.Value.Replace("1"">", "").Replace("</a", ""))
        Next
        Console.ReadKey()
    End Sub

End Module
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [lookaround assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

```
(?<=&sampleq=1"">)[^<]*(?=</a>)
```

Note the double quotes; I believe this is the way to escape a <kbd>"</kbd> in VB.NET.